# Can't switch to trunk

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I'm just getting started with SVN using the tools mentioned above, as for normal updating and committing I didn't have any problems, my problem is now when I'm trying to update my trunk with my branch changes.

First off, I started using the branch/tags option to created the branch from the trunk (is this the correct way to do it? or can I just copy the content from the trunk to the branch folder?).

After some changes done in the branch folder, I'm trying to copy those changes to the trunk, following other answers on here they say to switch the working directory to the trunk, but whenever I try to do so I get

```
'https://sc-mika/svn/repo.test/trunk' shares no common ancestry  with 'C:/Users/SC'.
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get branch's changes in trunk, you **must** merge branch into trunk (not just switch your WC) - read SVN Book

Comment: Specifically, [Chapter 4: Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html)

Comment: @SameerSingh - yes, thx for URL - I was too lazy to recover it